# AngularJS dynamically add key and value to an object

Tags: angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to ask you how I can add a key
and a value to an object. I want to get values from textareas, which
are generated with the help of ng-repeat, and to push them to an object.
courses: {}

With postman it works fine

```
courses :{
 "C#" : "C# 101",
 "C++": "C++ Advanced"
}
```

I have a collection called courses. Then with ng-repeat I create a textarea for each course and from this form I would like to put a key and a value to the object courses. key: course_code, value: course_desc. The problem is that I do not know how to store in the in the DB.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="course in courses">
    <label for="{{course.name}}">{{course.name}}: </label>
    <textarea  rows="3" ng-model="course.value" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

[The form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xDcb.png)

Comment: ng-repeat should look like ng-repeat="(key, value) in yourObject" then simply bind them to a model

Comment: Nothing in code shown or in question would even relate to using postman. Question is far too broad without more code context